# django lazy translation sometimes appears in response.data in unit tests

Tags: django, python-2.7, unit-testing, unicode, django-rest-framework

I'm writing unit tests for my django api written with django-rest-framework, and I'm encountering seemingly inconsistent response data from calls that generate 400_BAD_REQUEST.

When I make a request that fails because it references an invalid primary key, `repr(response.data)` is a string that I can check for the substring `"Invalid pk"`. But when I make a request that fails because it's trying to create a non-unique object, `repr(response.data)` contains `{'name': [<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f3ccdcb26d0>]}` instead of the expected `{'name': ['This field must be unique.']}`. When I make an actual `POST` call to the real server, I get the expected 400 response with `{'name': ['This field must be unique.']}`.

Here's a code sample:

```
class GroupViewTests(APITestCase):
    def test_post_existing_group(self):
        """
        Use POST to update a group at /groups
        """
        # create a group
        # self.group_data returns a valid group dict
        data = self.group_data(1)
        url = reverse('group-list')
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        # create the same group again
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        # this fails
        self.assertIn('must be unique', repr(response.data))
    def test_create_group_with_nonexistent_user(self):
        """
        Create a group with an invalid userid in it.
        """
        url = reverse('group-list')
        data = self.group_data(5)
        data.update({'users': ['testnonexistentuserid']})
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        # this succeeds
        self.assertIn('Invalid pk', repr(response.data))
```

I'm using only the default middleware.

From what I've found online, the `__proxy__` object is a representation of a lazy translation, which can be rendered as a string by calling `unicode(obj)` or `obj.__unicode__`. And indeed, `response.data['name'][0].__unicode__` does return the expected value, but calling `unicode(response.data)` instead of `repr(response.data)` still returns the object identified by memory address.

Can anyone explain what's going on here, and how to fix it? I can work around the issue for now, but I'd like to know the "real way" to fix the problem. Is it possibly a bug in django or django-rest-framework?

Answer (score 1):

Use `response.content` instead of `response.data`.

`response.content` contains the json output just like your client will receive it. It's also useful if you have custom renderer that change the response because `response.data` is not rendered, but `response.content` yes.

E.g :

```
import json
# we have to parse the output since it no more a dict
data = json.loads(response.content)
# if `response.content` is a byte string, decode it 
data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
```